# How to add custom php file to right sidebar?

Tags: pages, sidebar

I have created a quick contact form php file where visitor click it slides out a contact form to fill the details ,to add in right sidebar how to add in every pages and post any help how to add in every pages

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do that:

1. **Create a widget**  (Recommended)
       Here is official [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets). You can include your php file within `widget()` function of your widget class.
2. **Create and place a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)** in exiting wordpress default text widget.
   Here is sample code

   ```
   //Place this code in theme's functions.php

   add_shortcode('ContactForm', 'cf_shortcode');

   function cf_shortcode($att) {
      ob_start();
      include "path/to/php/file";
      return ob_get_clean();
   }
   ```

Then place `[ContactForm]` in wordpress default text widget.

[**Create a child theme**](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and override sidebar.php file of your theme there.